# How to exclude DEFAULTs from Python ConfigParser .items()?

Tags: python, configuration, configparser, defaults

I'm using ConfigParser to load in data from a configuration file as follows:

**test.conf:**

```
[myfiles]
fileone: %(datadir)s/somefile.foo
filetwo: %(datadir)s/nudderfile.foo
```

**load.py:**

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser({'datadir': '/tmp'})
config.read('test.conf')

print config.items('myfiles')
print config.get('myfiles', 'datadir')
```

**Output:**

```
$ python load.py 
[('datadir', '/tmp'), ('filetwo', '/tmp/nudderfile.foo'), ('fileone', '/tmp/somefile.foo')]
/tmp
```

I'm surprised that the defaults for variable substitution `('datadir', '/tmp')` are showing up as part of the .`items()` and `.get()` returns, as if they were values in the configuration file. Is this behavior expected? Any work arounds, so that I can simply iterate `.items()` without getting the default dictionary values in there, but still using the magic interpolation?

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Thanks!

*Update:* It's been pointed out that this is the expected behavior: defaults are just like any other name/value pair in the configuration file. Similarly, the name/value pairs in the configuration file are also available for "magic interpolation", so if I define:

```
foo: bar
zap: %(foo)snowl
```

I'll get `[... ('zap': 'barnowl')]`

That's pretty neat, but I'm still wondering if I can accomplish what I want to accomplish: iterate over the name/value pairs in my configuration files, with interpolation of variables, without the defaults.

My specific scenario is this: I wanted to initialize the config object with something like `{basedir: '/foo/bar'}`, as the absolute paths to certain files varies by installation. Then I need to pass that config object around to and have various other classes iterate through the files. I don't want every class that reads the configuration to have to know that it was initialized with certain defaults and that it should ignore them, as they are not actual files. Is this possible? Any way to hide the defaults from .item() and .get() but still have interpolation? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot fathom why this is the default behavior, let alone why there's no way to turn it off.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, I've found the [configparser.Configparser](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) class very helpful, but also lacking. [Others have, too](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout).

However, it *can* be subclassed and extended, sometimes nicely, sometimes not so nicely (=very implementation dependent)

Here's a solution for your problem, tested in Python3:

```
class ConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
    """Can get options() without defaults
    """
    def options(self, section, no_defaults=False, **kwargs):
        if no_defaults:
            try:
                return list(self._sections[section].keys())
            except KeyError:
                raise NoSectionError(section)
        else:
            return super().options(section, **kwargs)
```

This is one of the bad examples, because it is partially copying [the source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release32-maint/Lib/configparser.py) of `options()`. It would be nicer if the configparser base class `RawConfigParser` would provide an internal getter of options `_options(self, section)` which would incorporate the exception cast, and a `options()` which would make use of that. Then, in subclassing we could reuse the `_options()`.

For Python 2, I believe the only change is the `super()` call to `super(ConfigParser,self)`.

You can then use:

```
print config.options('myfiles', no_defaults=True)
```

And also use that list to iterate.

Comment: You're on the right track, however he asked about .items(), not .options().  I think this will get him there though.

Comment: I understood his question to be how to "iterate over the name/value pairs in my configuration files, with interpolation of variables, without the defaults." And that's what the above code does. To me that's an exact answer. Unfortunately, as often is the case, the poster of the question does not seem to be active. Otherwise we could have him decide if that's acceptable for an answer or not.

Comment: Yeah, the question runs on and on and needs focus.  He uses .items in the code, and in the last sentence.  He asks for name/val pairs, which is what .items does.  Options just returns keys.  Your answer helped me override .items though so thanks.

Comment: In Python2, `super` doesn't work at all because `ConfigParser` is an old-style class. (Yes, really.)

Comment: Also, note that `self._sections[section].keys()` (at least in Python 2) includes an entry called `__name__` in every section except `DEFAULTSECT`; this entry is not included by the default implementation of `options`, so it should probably be explicitly excluded here.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve made an account for the express purpose of answering this question. It seemed to be a top hit on Google when I was searching.

I dug into [the source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release32-maint/Lib/configparser.py) of `ConfigParser` to find what I think is a simple and efficient solution.

There’s a keyword argument to the `RawConfigParser` class (which `ConfigParser` inherits) called `default_section`. I was able to ignore the DEFAULT section of my config by instantiating with:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser(default_section=None)
```

I hope this can help someone else as well.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just filter out the defaults?

e.g.:

`filtered_items = [x for x in config.items('myfiles') if x[0] not in config.defaults()]`

Comment: Not if both have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser({'blahblahblah': 'blah'})
config.read('test.conf')
```

The `blahblahblah` key will also appear in `items`, not because it's a template in the .ini file, but because you specified it as a default. This is how ConfigParser treats defaults: if it can't find them in the file, it assigns their default values.

So it appears to me you have a simple confusion of concepts here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the defaults dictionary is used *both* to provide default values for certain keys, and for the "magic interpolation" of variables embedded within the configuration file.

Additionally, variables defined within the configuration file are also used for "magic interpolation", so if I define:

foo: bar
zap: %(foo)snowl

I'll get [... ('zap': 'barnowl')]

That's pretty neat, but I'm still wondering if I can accomplish what I want to accomplish: iterate over the name/value pairs in my configuration files, with interpolation of variables, without the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you only the key/value pairs in the *myfiles* section without also listing out those in *DEFAULT*:

```
list(set(config.items('myfiles'))-set(config.items('DEFAULT')))
```